# Como ajustar span ao lado das labels?

Tags: html, css

Estou com dúvida de como alinhar os `spans` ao lado dos `labels` conforme exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o meu html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="outputs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="spans">Prog. Degelos</span>
        <label class="labels active">Ativo</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="spans">Saídas</span>
        <label class="labels active">
        Refrigeração
      </label>
        <label class="labels active">
        Defrost
      </label>
        <label class="labels deactivated">
        Fans
      </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="spans">SETPOINT</span>
        <label class="labels">-5<sup> °C</sup></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="spans">DIFERENCIAL</span>
        <label class="labels">3<sup> °C</sup></label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocando um espaço mínimo nos títulos você pode fazer o alinhamento, um exemplo seria adicionar este css:

```
.outputs ul li span.spans {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: e para o texto span ficar na direita?

Comment: adicionei o alinhamento a direita, bastava apenas inserir text-align: right.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!